# Algorithms to fix audio feedback loop

Tags: audio, reference-request

I'm a student and I have been assigned to make a presenation on algorithms to prevent audio feedback loop (microphone feedback, that issue when you hear the voice echoed multiple times).

I looked online but I can't find any specific algoritm name that is used to achive this. I just need a name I can look online for books, whitepapers for that algorithm.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about echo cancellation (used for smart speakers or telecom systems) or actual feedback prevention ("howling" when you hold a microphone into a speaker) ?

Comment: So I'm not native english speaker I found out that what I was looking for is actually called howling. So just like you said the actual feedback prevention, if there are also circuits designed to prevent this and have same names that will be also great besided the software algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excellent reference on the topic. It's a survey on acoustic feedback control.
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.231.9808&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thank you. I came looking for copper and found gold. It's great.

Comment: You're welcome.